# What are the differences between app.UseRouting() and app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

As I'm trying to understand them, what are the differences between `app.UseRouting()` and `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1) might help you. Basically

1. UseMvcWithDefaultRoute() exists since .Net core 1.0
2. UseRouting() is added in .Net Core 3.0 which has added more functionalities to handle custom routes.

I mainly use first approach with mostly razor pages.
You can check "Endpoint routing differences from earlier versions of routing" in given link for more information. So, the final decision is whether you want to use Basic or Advanced Endpoint Routing

Comment: Tnx for answer but what are the differences  between app.UseRouting() and services.AddControllersWithViews()?

Comment: **AddControllersWithViews** is extension class to set up mvc which add support for controllers, api related features and views but not pages, not routing. **UseRouting** is routing middleware which enable endpoint routing. So even after you add **AddControllersWithViews**, you still need to configure routing. .Net core is open sourced so you can check all their codes from this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc/src/MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 2):

UseRouting is an advanced method. It just matches request to an endpoint. This is usually followed by useEndpoints() which actually executes matched endpoint. It doesn't necessarily indicate relation between routing and MVC.

UseMvcWithDefaultRoute takes care of everything. It is actually a convenience method for  :

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

So it's strictly  about MVC, also it follows the default routing(e.g. api/students/1). Nothing advanced.